# Removing strings in between two strings django templates

Tags: python, django

I have objects that reference other names of objects to save database transactions

so when I render the html page It prints a string like so `(u'aRandomModel253', 0)` <----that is the exact string it prints now I need to get 'aRandomModel253' out of that string so I can organize my webpage like so `<li><a href="/webapp/model/{{ aRandomModel253 }}">{{ aRandomModel253 }}</a></li>`

I would like to preform this logic in the template if possible and I would not like to change how that object is organized it had taken a long time to get it organized the way I wanted it.

Comment: If it's a tuple, you can use indexing in the template code. The syntax for indexing into tuples or lists in a template looks like this: `{{ aRandomModel253.0 }}` to get the first item.

Comment: @HåkenLid its a model that saves strings of a tuple :|

Comment: You could use `(name, number) = ast.literal_eval("(u'aRandomModel253', 0)")` to convert the string back to a tuple before passing it to the template.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string splicing.  If the thing you want is always in single quotes you could use `str.find()`

Ex:

```
String = "(u'aRandomModel253', 0)"

ModifiedString = [String.find("'"):String[String.find("'"):].find("'")]
```

This splices the string from the first occurrence of `'` to the character before the second `'`.  If you need more explanation please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Used a custom tag filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def number_and(value):
   return find_between(value,"'","'")



 def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
       start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
       end = s.index( last, start )
       return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
       return ""
```

Then in the template

```
{% load number_and %}
<html>{{model|number_and}}</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like your object is a tuple. If not, then it likely has some other `.name` property or something (and if not, you should be able to add it):

```
<div>{{ model.0 }}</div>
```